# How to group data by invoicing dates from 26th of the previous month until 25th of the present month?

Tags: mysql

The invoicing process groups the services made from the 26th of the past month until the 25th of the present month. So I want to group by client_id how much they have to pay for each month.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| person_id | client_id | service_id | price | service_date |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 101       | 1001      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-11-20   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 106       | 1001      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-11-24   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 102       | 1002      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-11-25   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 105       | 1001      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-11-26   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 103       | 1002      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-12-02   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
| 111       | 1002      | 301        | 1000  | 2019-12-05   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------------+
```

From the above data I would expect the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| client_id | total     | month      |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1001      | 2000      | november   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1002      | 1000      | november   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1001      | 1000      | december   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1002      | 2000      | december   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

EDIT: service_date is date in %d/%m/%Y format

EDIT2: I changed the date format for service_date to %Y-%m-%d

Db-fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1Xty9c1SAp2PfaWCC4WvK/0

Comment: What is the datatype for `service_date`?

Comment: Is date in format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: I mean the column datatype in the MySQL table, I assume it's `VARCHAR`, right?

Comment: is date type. It should be in %Y-%m-%d format, actually... I will correct that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired results you need to group by the adjusted month (and year). The easiest way to compute these is by taking advantage of the fact that MySQL treats a boolean value as 1 or 0 in a numeric context, thus we can use:

```
(MONTH(service_date) + (DAY(service_date) >= 26) - 1) % 12 + 1 AS month_num
YEAR(service_date) + (MONTH(service_date) = 12 AND DAY(service_date) >= 26) AS year
```

Since we have to use these values to generate the month name (but we need the numeric values for ordering), it's easiest to compute them in a subquery (or a CTE if you are using MySQL 8+):

```
SELECT client_id,
       total, 
       year, 
       MONTHNAME(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month_num, '01')) AS month
FROM (SELECT client_id, 
             SUM(price) AS total,
             (MONTH(service_date) + (DAY(service_date) >= 26) - 1) % 12 + 1 AS month_num,
             YEAR(service_date) + (MONTH(service_date) = 12 AND DAY(service_date) >= 26) AS year
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY client_id, month_num, year
) t
ORDER BY client_id, year, month_num
```

Output (for my expanded demo)

```
client_id   total   year    month
1001        2000    2019    November
1001        1000    2019    December
1001        2000    2020    January
1002        1000    2019    November
1002        2000    2019    December
1002        1000    2020    January
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1Xty9c1SAp2PfaWCC4WvK/1)